# SQL AG Secondary as a Primary of a 2nd group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, alwayson

Wanted to get your thoughts on trying to load balance my 2 node Always On AG (SQL 2016).

Currently I have x Databases in one group with one listener and 2 nodes (primary/secondary).

I want to try to utilize the secondary so that it is not just sitting there and create a 2nd availability group and 2nd listener and have the currently secondary become primary for the new group and the primary for the first group to be secondary for the 2nd group.

In theory this should work but wanted to know if anyone thinks it is a bad idea?

The main downside I can see is that patching would be a bit more complicated since I would not be able to simply patch the secondary whenever I want since it would be a primary for a set of databases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of this type of configuration. Why? It presumes that both nodes are available most (if not all of the time). I assume that your nodes are right-sized (within reasonable expectations of future usage) in terms of CPU, RAM, etc. What happens if one of those servers goes on extended hiatus? Can your one remaining server run the workload of both AGs?

Your second node isn't "just sitting there". It's replaying your transactions from the primary and doing the important job of providing redundancy.

Comment: I agree that in case where the primary server is on a longer than expected hiatus this may not be the best solution, however the primary is configure to handle all the loads of the databases as is the secondary so in case where one of the two nodes needs to take over, it will be able to handle the load without issues.  I am just seeing if I can utilize the secondary's resources more and off load the primary a little.